# Input user name and each user has their respective rights?

Tags: android

I am just learning Android, I input user name and each user has their respective rights.

**For example,**

- User1 has the right of Purchase Order Entry and printed Recap Purchases.
- User2 has Sales and Sales Recap.

  I want when User1 login will look for Purchase Order Entry and Recap Purchases while others are invisible, so also when User2 login that looks Sales and Recap Sales while others are invisible.

I've searched the Internet and there's no matching like I want.
May I ask for a sample program ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've added:
master.add (GROUP1, ORDERPEMBELIAN, 1, "Purchase Order");
but the result, Purchase Order, Recap Purchase repeatedly.
Help me with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's role of backend also if your app  not offline ->

Steps to follow:

when you  login to your app you need a key from server that you can differentiate  is it Purchase or sales .

Save the key value in local database like sharedPrefernce.

Now you can play around in your app using the key.